# How to use QFileDialog to open file with .mid suffix

Tags: python, pyqt5, file-extension, qfiledialog, mido

I have created a subclass for an option to Open File. Alongside PYQT5, I have imported the python library Mido & py-midi in order to read the MIDI files. If my logic is correct. I will use PYQT5's FileDialog in order to retrieve a file, assign it to a variable and then use Mido to read that said MIDI file when I Will then use py-midi to edit these files

```
class OpenDialog(QFileDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OpenDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("Open")
        self.setFixedSize(1000, 450)

        buttons = QDialogButtonBox.Open | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel

        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(buttons)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # OpenedFile =
```

I have commented out OpenedFile becuase i plan to use this as a variable to link to the opened files. However, I am unsure how this can be done in PYQ5. Furthermore, how to do this with a specific file extension.

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you explain me better

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're a bit confused on how QFileDialog works.

First of all, by default Qt tries to use the *native* file dialog the system provides, so generally you should not try to create your own by subclassing, unless you need *very* special behavior.

Then, QFileDialog is a QDialog that already has its own (private) layout and widgets, including the area in which files and folders are shown, a text field for the path, and standard Open/Cancel buttons.

Since you only need to open a specific file type, there's absolutely no need for subclassing, as explained at the very beginning of the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#details):

> The easiest way to create a QFileDialog is to use the static functions.

Those are listed in the [static members](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members) and you are probably interested in [`getOpenFileName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName); do note that the static functions for files (not those for directories) always return a tuple including the path(s) and selected file type filter:

```
    def showOpenFileDialog(self):
        fileName, filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 
            'some/default/path/', 'MIDI files (*.mid)')
        if fileName:
            self.openMidiFile(fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
class FileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        self.setNameFilters(["Excel File (*.xlsx *.xls)","CSV File (*.csv)","Log File (*.log)"])
        self.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)

    def accept(self):
        super(FileDialog, self).accept()
```